# Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file error in custom context menu command

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

I'm trying to add a custom option to the context menu in windows 7 and I've made the appropriate modification needed in the registry and the option appears in the context menu the way I wanted  but when I try to run it windows gives me the following error message:

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item.
```

the command I'm trying to run:

```
@="c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.100 \"%l\""
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there really nobody who has an answer to this question?  I have the same problem, with a program under "c:\program files\...".  If I move it to a different folder, it works.  I assume that it's a security/privilege issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the absolute path to the Windows folder with an environment variable such as %SYSTEMROOT%:

```
@="%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.100 \"%l\""
```

If that still doesn't work, try replacing the default value's type in the key you want to create from REG_SZ to REG_EXPAND_SZ. You must do this from the command line or in a .reg file since it's not possible to do it on the regedit GUI. If you wanna use CMD:

```
reg.exe add <key_path> /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.100 \"%l\""
```

Also try removing the \" 's

I had to deal with the same issue and I finally managed to make it work. This is what it looks like in the registry editor (click for larger image):

[image: My solution]